# Python urllib2.urlopen with @ symbol in URL

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm playing around in Python and and there's a URL that I'm trying to use which goes like this

```
https://[username@domain.com]:[password]@domain.com/blah
```

This is my code:

```
response =urllib2.urlopen("https://[username@domain.com]:[password]@domain.com/blah")
html = response.read()
print ("data="+html)
```

This isn't going through, it doesn't like the @ symbols and probably the : too. I tried searching, and I read something about unquote, but that's not doing anything. This is the error I get:

```
 raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'password@updates.opendns.com'
```

How do I get around this? The actual site is "https://updates.opendns.com/nic/update?hostname=

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use urlencode! Not sure if urllib2 has it, but urllib has an urlencode function.  One sec and i'll get back to you.

I did a quick check, and it seems that you need to use urrlib instead of urllib2 for that...importing urllib and then using urllib.urlencode(YOUR URL) should work!

```
import urllib
url = urllib.urlencode(<your_url_here>)
```

EDIT: it's actually urlllib2.quote()!

Comment: could I possibly get an example? I'm reading the documentation, but it's not working out..

Comment: I was actually incorrect, it's quote, not urlencode (as the other user specified).  sorry about that. the quote function is available in urllib and urllib2, so you don't need to import urllib.  The code would just be urllib2.quote(<your url here>)

Answer (score 1):

URIs have a bunch of reserved characters separating distinguishable parts of the URI (`/`, `?`, `&`, `@` and a [few others](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)). If any of these characters appears in either username (`@` does in your case) or password, they need to be percent encoded or the URI becomes invalid.

In Python 3:

```
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> parse.quote("p@ssword?")
'p%40ssword%3F'
```

In Python 2:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote("p@ssword?")
'p%40ssword%3F'
```

Also, don't put the username and password in square brackets, this is not valid either.

Comment: I'm totally scratching head about this...I'm using the urllib import parse, but I get an error saying "ImportError: cannot import name parse. This is the url that I want to query which will send back basic text that I want to output hxxps://user@email.com:password@myurl.com/hosts=host  

I havePython 2.7.6 - thanks for your help!