# Python urllib2 unable to open url

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a URL in this format:

https://aLongStringWithNumbers:anotherLongStringWithNumbers@somewhere.com/admin/someAPICall.json

which looks like not something that Python's urllib2 can understand, keep getting errors when using that with urllib2.open:

```
raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
```

Is this a case where the library is not capable of interpreting that URL? obviously it works in the browser... Using Python 2.7

Any advice would be appreciated!
Thanks
- V

Comment: could you [edit] your post to provide the example which doesn't work?

Comment: that is a url that contains basic auth credentials... you can't simply add credentials to your url like you can in a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is interpreting the `:` as the port number in the URL. You need to force it to pull in as a url using something like `quote`

See quote from the non-accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529021/python-urllib2-urlopen-with-symbol-in-url)

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.quote('https://aLongStringWithNumbers:anotherLongStringWithNumbers@somewhere.com/admin/someAPICall.json')
```